# How to increase the speed of the network interfaces on an EC2 h1.4xlarge

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2

The h1.4xlarge instances are meant to be 10gbps capable but when I check in windows it shows a 1gbps.
There seems to be no config i can set on the eni, subnet or vpc to adjust this.

Anyone have a clue?
Windows 2008rs SQL Server 2008rs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it. Really.

The shown network speed in a VM may mean nothing. Hyper-V for example does the same - every virtual network adapter is a 1gbit adapter. Regardless how fast the physical network is. BUT: It can run at higher speeds than 1gbit. Just the "emulated" hardware never changes.

AMazon may be the same - they SHOW 1gbit but you can transfer faster. Try it out.

Comment: Thx Tom, We are experiencing what looks like transport errors, possibly driven by contention. the speed appears, as you say, very good around 100mb /sec for a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to TomTom's response, this also depends on the following condition: "Instances launched into the same cluster placement group are placed into a non-blocking 10 Gigabit ethernet network"